# Can I get images in my gallery to zoom in but not exceed the width that I've given them?

Tags: html, css

The pictures continually zoom out of my gallery and I can't get them to stay inside the border I've set. I've tried overflow: hidden, but it's not working. Additionally, I can't get the gallery to center itself and I've tried the center tag, text-align: center; and float.

```css
div.gallery {
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 400px;
  float: center;
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  display: inline-block text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

div.gallery:hover {
  border: 1px solid #777;
  -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  transform: scale(1.1);
  overflow: hidden;
}

div.gallery img {
  width: 400px;
  height: auto;
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  -moz-transition: all 0.9s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.9s;
  transition: all 0.9s;
  max-width: 400px;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
}

div.desc {
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div style="overflow: hidden;" class="gallery">
  <a target="_blank" href>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400" alt="Cinque Terre" width="800px" height="600px">
  </a>
  <div class="desc"> </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you don't post your markup we have no way of knowing what the CSS applies to.

Comment: Is that better? Sorry, this is my first time using stack overflow, so I didn't know how much to add.

Comment: No, not really. We need to be able to reproduce the issue. `28947875_10156229336525789_8535958480572492962_o.jpg` doesn't mean anything to anyone except you, who has the image. It doesn't even have to be the same, you can use a placeholder, but it should have the same size and you should make sure your [mcve] reproduces the issue. Note: I've updated your snippet to a live one. Please change the image dimensions to match your image size.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing this is closer to what you're after !?

```css
div.gallery {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.gallery-item {
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin: 1rem;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.1), 0 1px 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.07), 0 2px 1px -1px rgba(0,0,0,.06);
  transition: box-shadow .3s cubic-bezier(.4,0,.2,1);
}
.gallery-item:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 5px 6px -3px rgba(0,0,0,.1), 0 9px 12px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.07), 0 3px 16px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.06)
}
.gallery-item a {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
}

.gallery-item a img {
  transition: transform .3s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 0.2, 1);;
  display: block;
  width: 150px;
  height: auto;
}
.gallery-item:hover img {
  transform: scale(2);
}
div.desc {
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery"> 
  <div class="gallery-item">
    <a target="_blank" href>
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300" alt="Cinque Terre">
    </a>
    <div class="desc">Description</div>
  </div>
  <div class="gallery-item">
    <a target="_blank" href>
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300" alt="Cinque Terre">
    </a>
    <div class="desc">Description</div>
  </div>
  <div class="gallery-item">
    <a target="_blank" href>
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300" alt="Cinque Terre">
    </a>
    <div class="desc">Description</div>
  </div>  
</div>
```

In short, you need to place the `transform` on the inner element and the `overflow:hidden` on the outer element. You were transforming the entire `.gallery`.